# What is this Regex doing: new Regex(@"(?<!\\),");

Tags: c#, regex

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?<!\\\\),");
String test = "OU=James\\, Brown,OU=Test,DC=Internal,DC=Net";
```

This works perfectly, but I want to understand it.    I've been gooling without success.   Can somebody give me a word or phrase that I can use to look this up and understand it.

I would have thought that it should be written like this:

```
 new Regex(@"(\\\\)?,");
```

I've seen the `(?zzzzzz)` syntax before.   It's the `<!` part that I'm stumped by.

Comment: @Srinivas - he's got 6 questions.  Nothing wrong with 0% for newer users.

Comment: The last edit truncated the question, currently it terminates with "syntax before. It's the" which isn't well formed :-)

Comment: I might be wrong but I think because you use "@" symbol at the beginning of the string you only need two backslashes.

Comment: Justin - thanks.  I didn't realize that I was supposed to mark the accepted answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(?<!…)` is a [negative look-behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind). In your regex

```
(?<!\\\\),
```

the `,` matches a comma obviously. The `\\\\` matches 2 backslashes. Then `(?<!\\\\),` matches any commas *not preceeded by* 2 backslashes.

Therefore it will match the `,` before the OU and DC, but not between James and Brown:

```
OU=James\\, Brown,OU=Test,DC=Internal,DC=Net
                 ^       ^           ^
```

Answer (score 4):

The `<!` part indicates a [*negative lookbehind*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookbehind_assertion). The rest of the expression (just a comma) matches only if it's not preceded by a backslash (or two backslashes, depending on whether the title or the body of your question is the accurate one).